# How to capture second word of an http status code using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to capture the http status code name using regex.

This is the log file entry sample text:

```
Completed in 0.01434 (69 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00006 (0%) | DB: 0.00220 (15%) | 404 Not Found [https://www.sample.com/page/soaps/1.xml]
```

As everyone knows, the http status code varies for each log file entry. It can be either of the following:

```
200 OK 
401 Unauthorized
201 Created
422 Unprocessable Entity
302 Found
404 Not Found
```

My capture group should contain either of the following:

```
OK 
Unauthorized
Created
Unprocessable Entity
Found
Not Found
```

My current regex expression looks like this:

```
\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\([^)]+\))\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\([^)]+\))\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\([^)]+\))\D+(\d{1,3})\D+([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][a-z]{1,12}(\s[A-Z][a-z]{1,10})?)\D+(\[.*\])\K
```

But if you run it in www.regex101.com, you'll see that it doesn't register an http status code with two words (i.e. Unprocessable Entity and Not Found).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `^\d+\h+\K.*` if you are using PCRE. Or, capture this substring: `^\d+\s+(.*)`. See https://regex101.com/r/0tkGjz/1

Comment: You should put the longer alternation *first* (the one that matches two words separated by a space), otherwise one of the first two alternations (which will match just one word) will fulfill the pattern before the two-word alternation has been tested

Comment: @CertainPerformance the problem is, I'm using this to parse a log file, so I don't really know which one will come first, the longer alteration or the shorter one.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue - if the longer alternation fails, it'll try to match one of the shorter alternations. (but you want the longer one to match immediately, if it can, so put it first)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks bro I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex

```
.*\| (\d+)\s+((?:\w|[^\S\r\n])*)
```

The first capture group is the error code and the second is the message. Note that this doesn't capture the link and it works if there is no link.
The pieces are as follows

- .*\| -> dot is a greedy match so it captures everything up to the last `|`
- first capture group

  - \d+ -> one or more digits
- \s+ -> one or more spaces
- second capture group

  - ?: -> signals that this group is a non-capture group.
  - any word character *or* any space but no new lines zero or more (if you are sure that there is a message you can replace the star with a plus)

To not capture newline I put a double negative regex. `\S` means no white-space and I negate it with `^`. So `[^S\r\n]` means no white-space characters except new line.

Comment: it worked perfectly for my example, thank you. Unfortunately, the original entry contains more characters than the example I indicated above. It was my mistake for not showing it, I apologise.

Comment: Then could you update the question. It looks interesting and I would like to see how it is solved.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is a bit hard to understand it here.

Comment: I think this should work `.*\| (\d+)\s+((\w|[^\S\r\n])*)` try it and if it is ok I'll update the answer when you update the question. In this one, the first capture group is the code and the second is the message.

Comment: I tried ".*\| (\d+)\s+((\w|[^\S\r\n])*)" and it worked but somehow it also has a capture group that only contains the last letter of the status code.

Comment: That puzzled me a bit too. I think that is because of the internal capture group in the second group.

Comment: I'll keep trying to get just the right regex expression, but your's was way more efficient and shorter than mine, thank you! I just started learning it today so I'm not that good yet. Please do keep me updated if you get it. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I'll see what I can add to the answer. Please up vote or accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: looking forward to it!